# using siunitx with calc latex-mode

Tags: latex, calc

I'm looking for a way to customize the LaTeX language mode in calc so that:`3 m/s`
gets displayed like
`\SI{3}{\meter\per\second}` instead of `\frac{3 m}{s}`. That would be very useful for yanking into a LaTeX buffer.

Does someone know of some some elisp code to that effect ?